# Collapsed slider returns console-error while hovering the menu items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, antd

I'm trying to add the *collapsed* function to my Antd *Slider*.

But since I add `collapsible`, I'm having an error when I hover the menu item.
`<Sider collapsible collapsed={sliderCollapsed} onCollapse={(value) => setSliderCollapsedWithCookie(value)}>{getMenu()}</Sider>;`

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAoOD.png)

Do you know where that can come from?

Thanks for the help!